# CMakeLists.txt: Install Python

Tags: python, catkin, rospy, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the best way to install python libraries with a package?

[This tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt#Installing_Python_Executable_Scripts) says how to do Python scripts, and I know you also need a [setup.py](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/catkin/html/user_guide/setup_dot_py.html), but I'm having trouble running `import easy_markers` with the deb package generated from [easy_markers](https://github.com/DLu/wu_ros_tools/tree/groovy/easy_markers)

(and now that I checked, I apparently can't run either of my scripts in the package either using rosrun)

You can download and test this package with `apt-get install ros-groovy-easy-markers`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187191/cmakelists.txt:-install-python/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2014-07-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-07-22**:
Does the `import easy_markers` work now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For Python 3 migration reasons, the recommended install method has changed from `install(PROGRAMS ...)` to `catkin_install_python(PROGRAMS ...)`.

See the how-to page for [installing Python scripts and modules](http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/installing_python.html).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2014-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-07-22**:
Then it is unfortunate that the tutorial on the wiki is out of data: http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt#Installing_Python_Executable_Scripts

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2014-07-23**:
Yeah. It's hard to find and fix all the stuff on the wiki. If I still remember about this problem, I'll fix it when I get back from vacation. Please open an issue for catkin, so it does not get lost.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-07-23**:
I will open an issue. Keep enjoying (hopefully) your vacation and not worrying about caktin :-).

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2014-07-30**:
http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt#Installing_Python_Executable_Scripts fixed in the wiki now.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-07-30**:
Thanks joq

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From looking at your package, the first thing I notice is that the released version is 0.1.0, and the version in the repository is 0.1.1. Did you forget to do a release of the latest version?

Looking at the source repository, there's only one thing that stands out:

For installing python scripts, the most reliable method is to use CMake's `install(PROGRAMS ...)` because it automatically sets the executable bit on your programs. Without it, your scripts will be installed, but they won't always be executable, so rosrun won't be able to find them.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-07-30**:
it should be noted that @joq 's answer should be preferred